# create sequence without NA's

Tags: r, sequence, na

I want to create a sequence but my variable has missing values like this

```
a <-  as.numeric(c(19,20,22,"NA",44,55,10,40))
seq(min(a),max(a),10)
```

I get this error

```
Error in seq.default(min(a), max(a), 10) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

Can I exclude the missing values from seq function? Without modifying the variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `min` and `max` functions have a `na.rm` argument, which can be used to ignore the NA values - see `?min`:

```
> seq(min(a, na.rm = TRUE), max(a, na.rm = TRUE), 10)
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
```